# C# calling unmanaged C++ using CLI wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, wrapper

I've been reading multiple examples from here and other sources on how to accomplish this.  Recently I followed this specific example which had been linked to in multiple other similar questions.

https://dorodnic.com/blog/2014/12/10/calling-cpp-by-example/

However even when directly importing this project from github it still presents an error in the C# project where it cannot reference the the C++ CLI code.  "The type or namespace could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)".  This is the same error I find while following other examples myself.  Could anyone please explain to me why this fails and/or suggest steps to fix it?

Edit: adding code here to save time.

```
//Logic.h
#pragma once

namespace MeaningOfLife
{
    namespace Cpp
    {
        // This is our native implementation
        // It's marked with __declspec(dllexport) 
        // to be visible from outside the DLL boundaries
        class __declspec(dllexport) Logic
        {
        public:
            int Get() const; // That's where our code goes
        };
    }
}
```

```
//Logic.cpp
#include "Logic.h"

int MeaningOfLife::Cpp::Logic::Get() const
{
    return 42; // Really, what else did you expect?
}
```

```
//Logic.h CLI
#pragma once

namespace MeaningOfLife
{
    namespace Cpp
    {
        // First a Forward Declaration to Cpp::Logic class:
        class Logic; // This allows us to mention it in this header file
        // without actually including the native version of Logic.h

        namespace CLI
        {
            // Next is the managed wrapper of Logic:
            public ref class Logic
            {
            public:
                // Managed wrappers are generally less concerned 
                // with copy constructors and operators, since .NET will
                // not call them most of the time.
                // The methods that do actually matter are:
                // The constructor, the "destructor" and the finalizer
                Logic();
                ~Logic();
                !Logic();

                int Get();

                void Destroy();

                static void InitializeLibrary(System::String^ path);
            private:
                // Pointer to our implementation
                Cpp::Logic* _impl;
            };
        }
    }   
}
```

```
//Logic.cpp CLI
#include "Logic.h"
#include "..\MeaningOfLife.Cpp\Logic.h"
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

MeaningOfLife::Cpp::CLI::Logic::Logic()
    : _impl(new Cpp::Logic()) 
    // Allocate some memory for the native implementation
{
}

int MeaningOfLife::Cpp::CLI::Logic::Get()
{
    return _impl->Get(); // Call native Get
}

void MeaningOfLife::Cpp::CLI::Logic::Destroy()
{
    if (_impl != nullptr)
    {
        delete _impl;
        _impl = nullptr;
    }
}

MeaningOfLife::Cpp::CLI::Logic::~Logic()
{
    // C++ CLI compiler will automaticly make all ref classes implement IDisposable.
    // The default implementation will invoke this method + call GC.SuspendFinalize.
    Destroy(); // Clean-up any native resources 
}

MeaningOfLife::Cpp::CLI::Logic::!Logic()
{
    // This is the finalizer
    // It's essentially a fail-safe, and will get called
    // in case Logic was not used inside a using block.
    Destroy(); // Clean-up any native resources 
}

string ManagedStringToStdString(System::String^ str)
{
    cli::array<unsigned char>^ bytes = System::Text::Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(str);
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> pinned = &bytes[0];
    std::string nativeString((char*)pinned, bytes->Length);
    return nativeString;
}

void MeaningOfLife::Cpp::CLI::Logic::InitializeLibrary(System::String^ path)
{
    string nativePath = ManagedStringToStdString(path);
    LoadLibrary(nativePath.c_str()); // Actually load the delayed library from specific location
}
```

```
//C#
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MeaningOfLife.WPF
{
    using Cpp.CLI;
    using Microsoft.Win32;

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var fileOpenDialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                CheckFileExists = true,
                Filter = "Native Library|MeaningOfLife.Cpp.dll",
                InitialDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
            };

            var result = fileOpenDialog.ShowDialog(this);
            if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
            {
                Logic.InitializeLibrary(fileOpenDialog.FileName);

                using (var wrapper = new Logic())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The answer is " + wrapper.Get());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs at the using Cpp.CLI and then at the calls to Logic because of that.

Just as a follow up I also tried this example and received the same error in the comparable place in the code.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/

Comment: Your CLI wrapper class will output an assembly that you need to reference in the managed, C#, class.  Based on the error, it looks you are not referencing the assembly.

Comment: Right and I thought I did that correctly.  I'll update this with some code to save time.  Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a using directive or assembly reference.  The former the most obvious reason from that web page, MainWindow.cs is missing the using directive that is needed to let the compiler recognize the Logic class.  It needs `using MeaningOfLife.Cpp.CLI;` to compile correctly.  Or the other way to do it, spelling the full name: `var wrapper = new MeaningOfLife.Cpp.CLI.Logic()`

Comment: MeaningOfLife only gives me the option of `MeaningOfLife.WPF`.  `MeaningOfLife.Cpp` isn't recognized.  The C# has the CLI as a reference which I thought would correct that but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: You will might have an easier time using `#pragma unmanaged` rather than using two separate assemblies for the cpp/cli classes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/managed-unmanaged?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by:
A)removing and adding back the WPF portion of the application
B)setting the "Copy Local" property of the CLI reference to true.

The reason I'm following these examples is to learn more about this process due to lack of knowledge. I do not think this is the real answer but it did solve my immediate issue.